# Samsung Galaxy 5 Wi-fi stops working: "ar6000 driver fails to load"

Tags: wi-fi, usb-drivers, samsung-galaxy-5

My Galaxy 5 has this problem for some months now: wifi stops working, I try to enable it and the phone says "Error" without any other further information. The only way to make it work again is rebooting the phone. I think this problem has been related here before.

But I managed to save the system log and got the following:

```
08/04/2011 23:01:50 [ERROR] WifiService(166) setWifiEnabledDialog: true
08/04/2011 23:01:50 [ERROR] WifiService(166) ****************setWifiEnabledDialog(), allowWifi****************true
08/04/2011 23:01:50 [INFORMATION] WifiService(166) setShowAccessPointListDialog():true
08/04/2011 23:01:50 [INFORMATION] WifiService(166) setWifiEnabledDialog(): true
08/04/2011 23:01:50 [INFORMATION] wlan_tool(11010) wifi loading 
08/04/2011 23:01:51 [INFORMATION] wlan_tool(11014) Driver is initialized. load it 
08/04/2011 23:01:51 [INFORMATION] wlan_tool(11021) ar6000 driver fails to load 
08/04/2011 23:01:51 [INFORMATION] wlan_tool(11029) wifi unloading
```

I'm trying to understand what's going on here. What exactly is ar6000? Maybe the network interface? How can I get more information about the error itself?

I have already uninstalled almost any app that could change the wifi behavior, and the problem persists. Juice Defender is still installed, but the problem already existed before I first installed it.

Comment: ar6000 is the driver for the [Atheros 6k Wifi chipset](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/ar6k). From browsing [on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=12326516&highlight=ar6000#post12326516), it seems to be a common issue with Galaxy, not sure if there is any fix yet, though many reported that reboots works.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed this is a pretty common problem unfortunately. I had the hope that bringing this log would help to understand the causes, but up to now it's being useless. Thanks for the link about the driver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen a number of people report that the WLAN test dialer code will allow the driver to reload properly ([example](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-mini-s5570/293451-wifi-error-android-2-2-froyo-samsung-galaxy-mini.html#post2669723)). I believe it's `*#*#526#*#*` on many Samsung phones, but [this post](http://androidforums.com/desire-tips-tricks/166750-google-android-hidden-secret-codes.html#post1512985) indicates that it may also be `*#*#528#*#*` or `*#*#232339#*#*`. This may not work on all devices, since manufacturers tend to include/remove different dialer codes almost at a whim.

If you're unfamiliar with dialer codes, simply open your dial pad and enter the sequence as though you were attempting to dial the number `*#*#526#*#*`. Your phone should then jump to the WLAN test facility.

Comment: great! it worked. :-) finally a better solution than restarting the phone.

Comment: All three of these codes bring up the correct interface on my GT-5570, which manages to successfully load the drive; unfortunately it then fails to find any networks when it scans.

Answer (score 2):

Something that's helped me with [similar Wi-Fi errors](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14162/1465) on my Vibrant is the [Blade Wi-Fi Fix](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bladewififix).  You might give it a shot and see if it works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've tried on several models of Galaxy's is to do a Factory Reset in the "Settings" menu. For some reason the WiFi drivers get corrupt and a reset fixes this every time.

Answer (score -1):

http://wiki.openmoko.org/wiki/AR6K

wifi driver issue, factory reset or firmware upgrade could help you.

Comment: Answers that provide no information except a link to somewhere else are not answers at all. What happens when that link stops working, for instance?