# How can I prevent my Wi-Fi connection from glitching?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, wi-fi, services, processes

Occassionally my Wi-Fi goes into this weird state where the phone "thinks" I'm connected, but the connection simply doesn't work.  Apps still seem to think I have connectivity, though they can't actually connect to anything, and the status bar still shows that I'm connected to Wi-Fi.  Turning Wi-Fi off and back on resolves the issue, and this occurs on multiple networks.

It seems sort of like whatever service manages the Wi-Fi connection gets killed occasionally.  It usually happens when I've been playing a game (that doesn't access the Internet) for a while or if my phone's been sitting for a while; it never happens while I'm actively using the connection.  I have my Wi-Fi timeout set to "Never" and the normal timeout isn't the issue since my phone regularly lasts several hours without the Wi-Fi dying.  Sometimes it dies a couple times in a day, and recently I went a week or so without it happening.

How can I fix this or prevent the service from being killed (if that's indeed what's happening)?  Shouldn't that be a system process that never gets killed?  (Does Android ever kill system processes other than when they crash?)  Could it be related to TouchWiz?  I have an SGS Vibrant running 2.2 (Bionix NextGen v1, but this has occurred on multiple ROMs).

Comment: My wife's Galaxy S Captivate has been experiencing a similar issue.  It's running CM7 nightlies, so it doesn't look like it's limited to TouchWiz.

Comment: Have you considered that it may be a problem with the custom ROM? I don't think that android is to blame for this. But this behavior sounds like an old/buggy WiFi driver, which is where the sock rom may be better.

Comment: @Flow My ROM is heavily-stock based, as are others I've tried; the drivers are stock, anyways.

Comment: FTR, I've gone through two Captivates.  The first one was so buggy, that practically nothing worked (including this WiFi issue).  I took it to ATT; they verified it was defective and replaced.  However, I still had issues with WiFi.  I've installed the app and look forward to wifi improvements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be a solution, but it's more a hint at the issue:

The ZTE Blade suffers with losing it's Wi-Fi connection when it comes back from sleep. Perhaps you have a similar issue?
The app [Blade Wifi Fix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bladewififix) by AA Android available from Google Play Store, fixes it on the Blade, you could give it a try:

> Some people with the ZTE Blade / Orange San Francisco phone find that the Wifi doesn't always come back on after the phone wakes up from being locked or asleep.
>
> Install this and you wont know its there until you wake up your phone and the Wifi jams, at which point it will flash a message to tell you its fixing it.