# Wifi sleep policy not working

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-nexus-s, google-talk, standby

I tried some stuff I found about sleep policy. I obviously tried setting it to **Never**, I tried the **Wi-Fi keep alive** app, it doesn't seem to work.

When I let the phone lie for a few minutes and then wake it, the wifi icon is grey and i cannot connect to anything right away, I have to wait till it turns green. This also messes up my GTalk, plenty of times i found out someone wrote to me only by manually opening the Talk app and waiting for it to sync (there was the red *unconnected* line at the bottom).

How do I fix this?

I have Nexus S, if that helps.
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14162/how-can-i-prevent-my-wifi-connection-from-being-killed

Comment: I read that question, but it didn't provide sufficient answer and I wasn't sure it's exactly what I mean, so I rather started a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was frustrated for a long time with the same problem. An app called [Wifi Fixer](http://wififixer.wordpress.com/) seems to have fixed it. Hope that helps you too.

Comment: Just an additional note... the problem went away with an OS upgrade, so Wifi Fixer is no longer needed, at least in my experience.