# Poor performance on Wifi compared to 3G

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, wi-fi, samsung-captivate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prevent my WiFi connection from glitching?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14162/how-can-i-prevent-my-wifi-connection-from-glitching)

I have consistent hanging/speed issues with my Apps when I use WiFi compared to 3G.

For instance, last night, I played a move with Word With Friends and the app said "Sending Move...".  It sat there for a while so, out of curiosity, I just turned the display off and went to bed.  When I turned the display on that morning, I still saw the "Sending Move.." screen.

I closed the app, turned off WiFi (thereby enabling 3G) and then loaded WWF.  The move sent instantly.  Other WiFi apps do the same thing; Facebook for instance hangs constantly on WiFi.  Also, there are times I open up the browser and it responds with "Can't connect"...even though the icon at the top of my screen says I'm connected to WiFi.

Usually, if I take the battery out, put it back in, let the phone reboot, WiFi resumes back to normal.  However, this is cumbersome.

I realize it could be a router issue though I have other devices connected to my router and they work fine 100% of the time. (One of the other devices is my wife's iPhone :P)

Is there a way I can pinpoint what the issue is?

Or, even better, have you had this problem and have a fix for it?

Comment: is your router set as 802.11n? The galaxy s devices don't support 802.11n, even though they claim it does. Try making your router use 802.11g and see if it resolves the issues.

Comment: This is a known issue with the original Galaxy S series.  See the answer to my question for a partial solution, but I'm still looking....

Comment: Thanks @MatthewRead Got it installed.  Fingers crossed.  I searched this site before asking, but I did "title:wifi" as opposed to "title:wi-fi" and missed your post :P

Comment: Actually my title had "WiFi" until I edited it after seeing your post :P but it's pretty difficult to search on this site.  Using tags can help -- e.g., `[wi-fi]` in search.

Comment: haha...ok...well, I just have no excuse then. :)  Point noted.