# Wi Fi Sleep policy doesn't work on Galaxy Mini

Tags: wi-fi, standby, samsung-galaxy-mini

Set the WiFi Sleep policy as 'never' but when my new Galaxy Mini is in sleep mode wi-fi is turned off. I tried with a few apps like 'Keep WiFi' without success. Is anybody out there who actually got the same problem and solved it?

Comment: I'm guessing it's the same as [this issue](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14162/1465), a known problem.  Can you confirm?

Comment: not the same thing...I dont see any wifi icon on the state bar after 15 minutes on sleep mode.(it's not 'freezed' , it's disonnected) by the way I'm testing a new app as we're speaking

Comment: Please register your account if you want to be able to own and respond to your questions.  I think the answer posted to my question may still help you.

Comment: registered! hope to find a solution because this way I can't use apps such as Gmail, Viber and WhatsApp...