# GT-I5500 Wi-Fi error

Tags: 2.2-froyo, wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-5

I have working Wi-Fi connection. I can connect to any access point in range and I have no problems with passwords, etc.

But after some time (sometimes hours, sometimes days) my phone tries to connect to access point and it fails. In Wi-Fi settings I just have "Błąd" message which in English means "Error". Then I cannot connect to any network, I'm not eve able to scan available networks - Wi-Fi is totally dead.

When I reboot phone it starts to working normally again.

My phone specs:

```
Samsung Galaxy 5
GT-I5500
Android 2.2 - FROYO.XWJQ3
I5500XWJP4
```

Comment: Something that could be related: [Samsung Galaxy 5 Wi-fi stops working: “ar6000 driver fails to load”](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12883/981).

Answer (score 1):

I performed two steps to fix the issue:

1. Settings -> Wireless & network settings -> Wi-Fi settings -> click menu button and select Advanced, Select Wi-Fi sleep policy - > Select Never.
2. Dial `*#*#526#*#*` for WLAN Diagnostics. This will reload the Wi-Fi driver (I tried this before without step 1 and it rebooted my mobile).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I recently stopped to use wifi because my operator has cheap mobile Internet prices. I will check Your solution in future.